# MVC3 - getting red x instead of picture from db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting red x mark instead of the picture when storing in database. I believe I am having problems in the Views files. Please could someone have a look at this and tell me how to correct it. If I have wrong URL Actions please tell me which ones I should be using. Thanks in advance.

SubCategory2 Table has the following columns...

Column field > Picture1 :  Data Type > varbinary(MAX)

Column field > ImageMimeType : Data Type > varchar(50)

Index.cshtml file

```
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <td>
                <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "SubProductCategory2", 
  new { id = item.SubProductCategoryID})" alt="" height="100" width="100" /> 
           </td>
```

Edit.cshtml file
"Edit" is the method in the contoller. "ProductCategoryL2" is the method in the controller. "GetImage" is the method in controller. All these methods are in the same controller file called ProductCategoryControllerL2

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ProductCategoryL2", "GetImage", 
FormMethod.Post, new { @encType = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
  <div class="editor-field">
    <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "SubProductCategory2", new {    
    Model.SubProductCategoryID })" alt="" /> 
    @Html.ValidationMessage("Picture1", "*")
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="Create" size="23"/>
  </div>
}
```

ProductCategoryL2Controller.cs file

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection, 
    SubProductCategory2 editSubProdCat, HttpPostedFileBase image)
    {
        var r = db.SubProductCategory2.First(x => x.SubProductCategoryID 
        == id);

        if (TryUpdateModel(r))
        {
            if (image != null)
            {
              editSubProdCat.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
              editSubProdCat.Picture1 = new byte[image.ContentLength];
              image.InputStream.Read(editSubProdCat.Picture1, 0, 
              image.ContentLength);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("/");
        }
        return View(r);

   }

  public FileContentResult GetImage(int productId)
  {
      var product = db.SubProductCategory2.First(x => 
      x.SubProductCategoryID == productId);
      return File(product.Picture1, product.ImageMimeType);
  }
```

**Addition Note**
I am using MVC 3 framework. The GetImage method has been extacted from Steven Sanderson book Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework. So I am not sure if that will be a problem?

Comment: Are you NOT using MVC3?? You tagged it V2. .also tag by what database you use.

Comment: What is the type of product.Picture1 ?

Comment: @DiscoDude: Also, what is the value of product.ImageMimeType for case that is failing?

Comment: include output HTML may help also

Comment: @NickLarsen - type is varbinary(MAX)

Comment: @DiscoDude that is the type in the database, I want to know what the type is on the product class so I can tell which overload for the `File()` function you are calling.

Comment: @NickLarsen - value of product.ImageMimeType seems be null because I am getting error message - Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: contentType pointing at return File(product.Picture1, product.ImageMimeType);  public string ImageMimeType (get; set;) is in ProCat1 class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step I would take to debug would be to try the URL for the image in your browser directly.   Right-click on the red X, copy the url and paste it in your address bar.  If the url looks right you should be a better error telling you what the problem is.  If that fails, put a breakpoint in your GetImage routine to make sure the routes are correct and your method is getting called.  Try Fiddler to see the request being made and what your web server is saying.

My guess is that you have the action wrong.  It looks like you are linking to the GetImage action on the SubProductCategory2 controller when the method is on your ProductCategoryL2 controller.

Also I don't understand how your Model.SubProductCategoryID value is supposed to be mapped to your productId parameter.  Try changing these calls:

```
Url.Action("GetImage", "SubProductCategory2", 
    new { id = item.ProductCategoryID})
Url.Action("GetImage", "SubProductCategory2", new {    
    Model.SubProductCategoryID })
```

to these:

```
Url.Action("GetImage", "ProductCategoryL2", 
    new { productId = item.ProductCategoryID})
Url.Action("GetImage", "ProductCategoryL2", new {    
    productId = Model.SubProductCategoryID })
```

Comment: @JasonGoematt - I copied the URL and I get the following message...The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'productId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult GetImage(Int32)' in 'MvcMyApplication.Controllers.ProductCategoryL2Controller'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Comment: Sounds like it is that you are not passing the "productId" parameter as part of your route values, try using the code in my answer instead.  The first time in your code you set 'id', but your parameter is named 'productId', in the second one there doesn't seem to be a name specified, I don't know how that works.

Comment: @JasonGoematt - I copied your code, now the error says -Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: contentType pointing at return File(product.Picture1, product.ImageMimeType);

Comment: From from Steven Sanderson book Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework, he stated We don’t want either of these properties to be directly visible in the product-editing UI. We can use [ScaffoldColumn(false)] to exclude ImageMimeType from the automatically generated UI. We don’t need
to give any hints about ImageData because ASP.NET MVC’s built-in object editor template won’t scaffold
byte[] properties anyway—it only scaffolds properties of “simple” types like string, int, and DateTime.5. So I have done that and still getting the same error message?

Comment: If you breakpoint in your GetImage routine, what values do you show for product.Picture1 and product.ImageMimeType?

Answer (score 0):

Your input file field is called `Create`:

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="Create" size="23"/>
```

whereas the controller action parameter handling the form submission is called `image` (the one with `HttpPostedFileBase` type) => this parameter will always be `null` in your `Edit` controller action and nothing will be saved in the database.

Also the attribute is called `enctype` and not `encType` in the `Html.BeginForm` helper. Also inside the `GetImage` action ensure that `product.Picture1` represents a correct image byte array and that it's content type matches with `product.ImageMimeType`.

So for example to further debug this issue you could try to save it to some temporary file to see if it is a valid image just before returning. Also make sure that the `product` instance you have fetched from the database is not null:

```
 // if the content type is image/png:    
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\foo.png", product.Picture1);
```

Then ensure that `foo.png` open successfully with an image viewer.

Comment: How do I ensure that product.Picture1 represents a correct image byte array and that it's content type matches with product.ImageMimeType?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return file content as the value to your img's src attribute.  Your browser will need to issue a separate request for the image.

change your view to this:

```
<img src="GetImage/@(Model.SubProductCategoryID)" />
```

Comment: No luck. Changed both Index and Edit file

Comment: what do you get in your browser when you go directly to httx://mysite/GetImage/i (where i is a valid productId that has an image)?